# Receive Push Image in Android once Processing done

Tags: php, android, push-notification

My PHP server is connected to a camera which is remotely triggered using an Android phone. 
The android app will send parameters of photos to be taken to the server (e.g. ISO). Once the command is sent to the server, user is moved to the next Activity on the app where an ImageView inside a FrameLayout is present.

This ImageView will be updated when my server side program has taken the photo and has sent it.

This is my proposed idea. What protocol should i use to implement this communication? I have looked into Google Cloud Messaging but it mentioned something about a payload limit of 4kb.

I have looked at gSOAP and it seems to be geared at C++ applications.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Google Cloud Messaging (GCM), but instead of sending the image as part of the payload  send a URL where the image is accessible. Then when the application receives the message from GCM I would download the image from the server, and notify the user in an appropriate manner that the image has been captured.

There is no guarantee around GCM delivery time frames though. So if you're requiring a response pretty much immediately I would consider a socket connection between the server and the device, although this is a lot trickier to manage with the application lifecycle.